# Identifying data tables and columns from a SQL query

Tags: sql

I have the task of identifying all of the core data tables and their corresponding data columns from a SQL query **that has been copied into an Excel sheet and given to me**. I'm having trouble matching up what table some of the data fields are coming from in the code below, namely the columns in the first `SELECT` clause that have asterisks, as they are not linked to any specific table:

```
INSERT INTO table work.review
    SELECT 
        table1.person,
        *case_number,
        *case_date,
        *status,
        *reports
    FROM   
        example_a table 1,
        example_b table 2, 
        SELECT(case_number, open_date as open cases 
        FROM example_c) table 3
    WHERE  
        table1.case_number = table2.case_number
        AND table2.case_number = table3.case_number
```

Is it possible to identify where these fields are coming from without actually having the SQL script in SQL itself? **I do not have access to the live script, I *only* have the hard Excel copy of the script.**

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You should alias all your columns that you select, then you will have no doubt which table they come from. I.e., `select table1.person, table2.case_number, table2.case_date ...`

Comment: *why* are you having trouble? We can't see the table schemas but *you* can, either using SSMS to view the table definitions or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Comment: I just clarified my question--this is not a script I wrote nor has it been given to me in SQL. This is a SQL script that someone else has written and it was copied into Excel and then given to me to identify all the tables and fields.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.  Even if you have the original SQL script it is not possible unless you have access to the table metadata.

Comment: Okay thank you! All I needed was validation that this was not possible and that I wasn't missing something. Appreciate it!